# I Can SSH host computer but computer does not appear in Finder's Shared Computers List?

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh, remote-desktop

I want to connect via Apple's ScreenSharing.app , to my home mac from a separate network.

I verified that my host computer is listening on `port 5900`

I can SSH via unix command `ssh user@router.ip`

but I don't see the computer under the `Shared` computers list in `Finder`

- I can screen share when host and remote computer are on the same network
- Ive tried using Go > Connect to Server , using different input for the server address , but i'm not sure what I would type for a computer on a different network.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour is the protocol that is used to "discover" other computers and will list them in Finder.  Bonjour only works on the local network.

> I want to connect via Apple's ScreenSharing.app , **to my home mac from
>   a separate network.**

If it's on a separate network, you won't see them in Finder even though you can still reach them (`ssh`, `scp`, `ftp`, `http`, etc.).